# Rule for Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I apologize if this seems really stupid, but I've been stuck in finding the general pattern for the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}{1\cdot3\cdot 5 \cdots(2n-1)}$$

The numerator is simple enough, it's just $2^nn!$. But what I'm really having trouble is finding the rule for the denominator. I've been racking my brain, but I can't come up with anything. Maybe I'm not thinking correctly? But anyways, if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Aak. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what the numerator is, and you know what the numerator *times* the denominator is, then you know what the denominator is.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what "the numerator times the denominator" is? I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: By "the numerator times the denominator" I mean the product of the numerator and the denominator. The quantity $N\times D$ where $N$ is the numerator and $D$ is the denominator.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this right? Like I know for the first term, the product of NxD = 2 and N = 2, so D = 1. For the second term, the product of NxD = 24 and N = 8, so D = 3. I think what I'm really trying to say (if I'm understand you correctly) is how this will help find the rule for the denom.

Comment: The numerator is $N=2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)$. The denominator is $D=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)$. If you know what $N$ is and you know what $ND$ is, then you know what $D$ is. You stated in your question that $N=2^nn!$. The formula for $ND$ is even more obvious.

Comment: I'm honestly not seeing it? If I don't know what D is, how would I know what ND is?

Comment: Namely, $ND=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\dots(2n-1)\cdot(2n)=(2n)!$, so $D=ND/N=(2n)!/(2^nn!)$, and $N/D=(2^nn!)^2/(2n)!=4^n(n!)^2/(2n)!=2^{2n}/\binom{2n}n$.

Comment: $N$ is the product of all the even numbers from $2$ to $2n$. $D$ is the product of all the odd number from $1$ to $2n-1$. $ND$ is the product of **all** of those factors, i.e., all of the numbers, odd and even, from $2$ to $2n$.

Comment: Ahhh, now I feel really bad for missing something so obvious. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: For example, if $N=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$ and $D=2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8$, then $ND=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8=8!$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each factor in the numerator is greater than the corresponding factor in the denominator.  What does that suggest to you about the terms of this infinite series?

Comment: That each subsequent term will always be greater than the previous. But I don't see how that helps, or am I still missing something?

Comment: So does the series converge?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{\large{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2} \over \left(2n\right)!}}$